# AddScoped: How to call the right constructor function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I am looking for the correct C# code to inject this service in ASP.NET 5 MVC (core) in a way the defaults for the class apply.

If I add the scoped service below, the instance field values are *empty*.  If I do `var a = new HtmlSanitizer();`, instance fields are populated with non-null defaults like "a long string of values".

```
services.AddScoped<IHtmlSanitizer, HtmlSanitizer>();
```

If I rewrite the injection as below, instance fields are *populated*. Does this code match the intended effect as above?  Of course, why the difference in the resulting object?

```
services.AddScoped<IHtmlSanitizer, HtmlSanitizer>(
    _ => { return new HtmlSanitizer(); }
    // Why the difference?
    // Is this how one passes constant parameter values?
);
```

I used [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) and Asp.Net 5 in this example but I doubt it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually has less to do with `HtmlSanitizer` specifically and more to do with how .NET Core Constructor Dependency Injection works.

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#constructor-injection-behavior):

> Services can be resolved by using:
>
> - IServiceProvider
> - ActivatorUtilities:
>
>   - Creates objects that aren't registered in the container.
>   - Used with some framework features.
>
> Constructors can accept arguments that aren't provided by dependency
> injection, but the arguments must assign default values.
>
> When services are resolved by IServiceProvider or ActivatorUtilities,
> constructor injection requires a public constructor.
>
> When services are resolved by ActivatorUtilities, constructor
> injection requires that only one applicable constructor exists.
> Constructor overloads are supported, but only one overload can exist
> whose arguments can all be fulfilled by dependency injection.

In this context, you are using the IServiceProvider and the framework can "visit" arguments that are specifically of type `IEnumerable<T>`, which is what is required by the `HtmlSanitizer` [constructor](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer/blob/master/src/HtmlSanitizer/HtmlSanitizer.cs#L76):

```
public HtmlSanitizer(IEnumerable<string>? allowedTags = null, IEnumerable<string>? allowedSchemes = null,
    IEnumerable<string>? allowedAttributes = null, IEnumerable<string>? uriAttributes = null, IEnumerable<string>? allowedCssProperties = null)
{
    AllowedTags = new HashSet<string>(allowedTags ?? DefaultAllowedTags, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    AllowedSchemes = new HashSet<string>(allowedSchemes ?? DefaultAllowedSchemes, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    AllowedAttributes = new HashSet<string>(allowedAttributes ?? DefaultAllowedAttributes, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    UriAttributes = new HashSet<string>(uriAttributes ?? DefaultUriAttributes, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    AllowedCssProperties = new HashSet<string>(allowedCssProperties ?? DefaultAllowedCssProperties, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    AllowedAtRules = new HashSet<CssRuleType>(DefaultAllowedAtRules);
    AllowedClasses = new HashSet<string>(DefaultAllowedClasses, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

When the service resolver sees a constructor with arguments, it will attempt to visit each argument.  In the case of `IEnumerable<T>`, the arguments are specifically handled and default arrays will be created per the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceLookup/CallSiteRuntimeResolver.cs#L161):

```
protected override object VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
{
    var array = Array.CreateInstance(
        enumerableCallSite.ItemType,
        enumerableCallSite.ServiceCallSites.Length);

    for (int index = 0; index < enumerableCallSite.ServiceCallSites.Length; index++)
    {
        object value = VisitCallSite(enumerableCallSite.ServiceCallSites[index], context);
        array.SetValue(value, index);
    }
    return array;
}
```

You can prove this out with a very simple test harness:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    private ISet<string> _defaults = new HashSet<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
    private ISet<string> _filters;

    public Test(List<string> filters = null)
    {
        _filters = new HashSet<string>(filters.ToHashSet() ?? _defaults);
    }
}

public interface ITest { }
```

In this case, the parameter filters will be null and the defaults will be used instead when resolving `provider.GetService(typeof(ITest));`.  However, if I require an `IEnumerable` instead:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    private ISet<string> _defaults = new HashSet<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
    private ISet<string> _filters;

    public Test(IEnumerable<string> filters = null)
    {
        _filters = new HashSet<string>(filters.ToHashSet() ?? _defaults);
    }
}

public interface ITest { }
```

you will find that a default array is passed, causing the default filters to NOT be used.

By using the factory instantiation where you return `new HtmlSanitizer()`, you bypass this implementation behavior and pass null for each parameter, allowing the defaults to be used.

This is very surprising behavior and I was unable to find any documentation that describes this as expected behavior. I believe this may simply be an oversight by the .NET Core DI team since typically dependencies are intended to be non-IEnumerable types. It is also worth noting that this behavior does NOT apply to parameters of `IList<T>` or `ISet<T>` type.